# make qml item invisible by condition

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

So I have `Item { id: myItem }`, and want it becomes invisible if `obj.condition` is false.
This looks trivial:

```
Item {
  id: myItem
  visible: obj.condition
  enabled: visible
}
```

But such code set `visible to true for` myItem`even if out of view of user. For example if it is in scrollable area and invisible for user, or there is tabs and`myItem` is in inactive tab.

Also I do not want get key presses for invisible item, so as you can see I use `enabled: visible`, and setting `visible` for really invisible item also broke this.

So how can I separate `visible` as "visible on screen" and `visible` as "allow to see"?

Comment: I don't understand your issue. If an item is not visible on screen, you will not receive key presses (except for if the item still has focus). What is the actual problem with your code?

Comment: @m7913d In qml if item not visible on screen it is still recieve key events, you can read this in official documentation https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#visible-prop , and if you don't believe documentation try it by you self.

Comment: I'm aware of it, as already stated in my first comment. I just think that you should show a [mcve] of your problem and the undesired behavior you experience. In general, Qt doesn't provide a method to determine if an item is "visible on screen".

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
Item {
  id: myItem
  visible: true
  enabled: true
}
```

You can change the value of `condition` with an event like for a button :

```
Button {
  id: myButton
  onClicked: myItem.visible = true
}
```